# What is the correct, formal and polite way to say "I'll wait for your notice/decision"?

Tags: vocabulary

Assume you had a plan with someone like a work travel or something and then that person write to you that there may be a better plan so for a while don't fix things for the previous plan and wait. Now You want to reply his message with something formal and polite but I don't know what sentence or verb is correct. Is "I'll wait for your notice" ok? Or "I'll wait for your decision." or "I'll wait for the news" or maybe something else? And I will is better or I'm looking forward into?

Comment: All your choices work. I would add that "I am holding off any efforts until I hear from you."

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of opinion I'd say
however if i had to choose one I'll use "I will be waiting for your reply"
since, for some reason seems so friendly to me
Again, it's all personal preferences :)